# Issues with Postman Monitors

Tags: json, rest, automation, postman

I am having an issue with running my collection on the Monitors. It runs with no issues on the runner but does not on the Monitors.

It gives me error 401 Unauthorized only when I use the Monitors. I am using two different hosts under the same monitor.

I want to automate the collection to run automatically every x amount of hours every day. I made sure my workflow is working with the runner. However, it is not with the Monitors
I’ve already tried:

I use oAuth2.0 for the request that I am having issues with.
The request has pre-requests and tests.
The token is not expired.

[image: 1]

[image]

Comment: Is there anything in the monitor console log that gives you more information? Is this a publically accessible endpoint? How are to specifying the token in the requests?

Comment: Hey Danny, 
I am getting those errors: 


`72 12:05:50 Failed: Status code is 200
73 12:05:50 expected response to have status code 200 but got 401
74 12:05:50 TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
75 12:05:50 TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`
I do not get them when I am running the requests with the runner. 
The endpoint is not publicly accessible.

The collection is making a GET request from a platform, saving the values in the environment and then passing them to the POST request. 

I am specifying my token from the Authentication under the request.

Comment: @vcm monitor works only on public APIs , see with team whether there is any IP wightlisting enabled for that service etc

Comment: I did not realize that Danny meant by public as publicly listed. The website needs credentials to sign into. I was able to understand what is causing the problem, monitors are not using the headers and body. The token is in the header and the monitor is not putting the headers in the URL. That is what is causing the issue to happen. Any idea on how to solve it?